# Why must $f$ have a negative value?

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, inner-products

Let $V$ be the real inner product space of continuous functions $[0,1] \to R$ with $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 fg \ dx$ and let $a \in [0,1]$. Show that there is no non-negative function $f \in V$ such that:

$$\int_0^1 f \ dx = 1, \qquad \int_0^1 xf \ dx = a, \qquad \int_0^1 x^2 f \ dx = a^2. $$

I'm stumped. Here are some thoughts:

The conditions on $f$ are inner products, so we know:
$$\langle 1, f \rangle = 1, \qquad \langle x, f \rangle = a, \qquad \langle x^2, f \rangle = a^2.$$

At one point I though this statement might be false so in an attempt to produce a counter example I used these inner products to construct the projection $g$ of $f$ onto the subspace of $V$ spanned by $1,x,x^2$, but for all $a \in [0,1]$ that projection had some $x_0$ for which $g(x_0) <0$.

Using properties of inner products I can arrive at things like:

$$\langle x-a, f \rangle = 0, \qquad \langle x^2 - a^2 , f \rangle = 0, \qquad \langle x^2 - ax, f \rangle = 0,$$
so that $f$ is in the orthogonal complement of the span of $x-a, x^2-a^2, x^2 - ax$, but I cannot make that into anything useful.

I've also thought about considering $f$ as a probability density function for a random variable $X$ where $f$ takes value $0$ when $x \notin [0,1]$. Then $\langle 1,f \rangle = 1$ says that $f$ could possibly be a probability density function. Then $E[X] = a$ and $\text{Var}(X) = 0$ seem like they could lead to some kind of contradiction to $f$ being continuous, but I wasn't quite sure.

I've played around with Cauchy-Schwartz to look for inequalities that must be satisfied by $f$ and $a$, but didn't notice anything useful.

Recently I've been trying to use the Riez Representation Theorem, but I am only familiar with that theorem for finite dimensional vector spaces. I have read a bit about how it applies to Hilbert spaces but wasn't sure if that could be useful here.

What am I missing? Why must there exist some $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0) < 0$ ?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz sounds like a good idea.

Comment: You had a great idea with the probability density functions! What does a RV with zero variance look like?

Comment: @MatthewTowers It looks like some sort of degenerate distribution, which I assume are not continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider
$$\int_0^1(x-a)^2f(x)\,dx.$$
This equals zero. As the integrand is continuous, and non-negative, it must be
identically zero.

Comment: Or, in the probability language that OP was trying, zero variance means that $f$ is the law of the constant random variable $a$ which is not possible.

Comment: Ah so since $(x-a)^2 f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and $f$ is continuous, it must be that $f(x)$ is identically $0$, which contradicts $\int_0^1 f \ dx = 1$.